# Using JsonServiceClient in OOB Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, servicestack

Is it possible to use JsonServiceClient in Silverlight when running OOB (Out of browser)?

I have a backend system which expose a number of webservices using ServiceStack, and i would like to use ServiceStack on the client-side of the system also.

I am developing the client in Silverlight 5. When i test the client running inside a browser the JsonServiceClient works as expexted - but when running OOB (a requirement) it throws a exception stating "The DOM/scripting bridge is disabled." - which occurs because when running OOB you do not have access to the browser API - but are there any workaround?

The code which works in browser, but casts exception OOB:

```
var restClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://127.0.0.1:1030");
restClient.GetAsync<AgentModelResponse>("/agents",
  r =>
  {
    r.Agents.ForEach(x => Agents.Add(x));
  },
  (r, ex) =>
  {
    throw ex;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to host and access your web service using SSL, in order for web service calls to work in an OOB Silverlight app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(VS.96).aspx

Comment: I am running with elevated privs - so this is not the issue. Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old one but as I have just come across the same issue maybe it can still help others.
So this issue can be fixed by setting the ShareCookiesWithBrowser property of the client to false:

restClient.ShareCookiesWithBrowser = false;